# Is it worthy to create a wrapper function like this?

Tags: python

I have a few Python codes like this:

```
 workflow = [] 
 conf = {}
 result = []
 prepare_A(workflow, conf)
 prepare_B(workflow, conf)
 prepare_C(workflow, conf)
 result.append(prepare_D_result(workflow, conf))
 prepare_E(workflow, conf)
 #.... about 100 prepare functions has the same parameter list
```

I was wondering that whether I need to rewrite like this:

```
 workflow = [] 
 conf = {}
 result = []
 def prepare_wrapper(prepare_function):
         return prepare_function(workflow, conf)

 prepare_wrapper(prepare_A)
 prepare_wrapper(prepare_B)
 prepare_wrapper(prepare_C)
 result.append(prepare_wrapper(prepare_D_result))
 prepare_wrapper(prepare_E)
 #.... about 100 prepare functions has the same parameter list
```

Though it might reduce the burden of passing 2 parameters into the function each time, it might bring difficulties for those who read codes. Is there better ways to ameliorate the code quality in such situation?

Comment: Your question isn't following the FAQ in that your don't appear to be presenting real code. It would be better if you could show us an actual example.

Comment: Are you sure about this style of programming? all your "functions" work by performing side-effects, so your application will be a gigantic state container where any data structure can be modified anywhere else. Have you considered a more functional approach? (where functions that take values and return another values, no side-effects). It requires some more thought at first, but it pays off later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea, assuming your logic is really that straightforward:

```
workflow = [] 
conf = {}
result = []

steps = ((prepare_A, False),
         (prepare_B, False),
         (prepare_C, False),
         (prepare_D, True),
         (prepare_E, False))

for func, need_results in steps:
    res = func(workflow, conf)
    if need_results:
        result.append(res)
```

If you don't find that approach suitable, I'd suggest making your wrapper a class that encapsulates `workflow` and `conf`, and possibly `results` too.

```
class PrepareWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.workflow = [] 
        self.conf = {}

    def __call__(self, prepare_function):
         return prepare_function(self.workflow, self.conf)        

prepare_wrapper = PrepareWrapper()         
prepare_wrapper(prepare_A)  
prepare_wrapper(prepare_B)
```

Or, why not make all the prepare functions methods of this class?